# Type checking on results with pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I'm new using pyparsing, but I can't find how to solve this quite easy issue. I have (for the moment) a simple grammar, but I can' t find the way to discriminate the result of parsing according the types I defined in my grammar.

Maybe it' d be easier to explain it with an example. Supposing this element:

```
elem = foo | bar
```

When I invoke:

```
elem.parseString("...")
```

supposing the string matches with my grammar, how can I discriminate if it matches with ' foo' or with ' bar'? I get an instance object of ParseResults with no such metadata.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could assign a name to them (a convoluted example using Literal):

```
foo = Literal('foo').setResultsName('foo')
bar = Literal('bar').setResultsName('bar')
grammar = foo | bar
parsed = grammar.parseString('bar foo')
print parsed
# (['bar'], {'bar': [('bar', 0)]})
print parsed.asDict()
# {'bar': 'bar'}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't understand why they don't put the name by reflection, but at least setResultsName() works.

Comment: Ummm, the problem performing asDict() is that I lost the order, which is important in this case...

Comment: @Wikier - unfortunately, you can't use reflection in assignments in Python. The closest you can get is to use the abbreviated form  `expr(name)` is equivalent to `expr.setResultsName(name)`, or in your case: `foo = Literal('foo')('foo')`  Then when you walk the results, use `getName()` on the returned ParseResults object.

Answer (score 4):

Jon Clements' answer is the correct one, here is just some extra code in support of his post, showing how to use `getName()` to detect which term you got:

```
>>> from pyparsing import Literal, OneOrMore, Group
>>> bar = Literal('bar').setResultsName('BAR')
>>> foo = Literal('foo')('FOO') # using short form
>>> grammar = OneOrMore(Group(foo | bar))
>>> parsed = grammar.parseString('bar foo')
>>> for p in parsed: print p[0], p.getName()
... 
bar BAR
foo FOO
```

Comment: Thanks Paul - I was hoping you'd pitch in. I wasn't aware of `.getName` so I've learnt something as well +1 (Mind you - being the author of the library gives you a slight advantage ;))

Comment: Yes, I didn't want to chime in and snipe your checkmark from you - I need all the pyparsing contributors I can get (whom I typically reward with +1's btw).